# Removing apostrophe from all file names

Tags: shell, command-line, rename

I tried to remove apostrophe from all files' names in the directory.

```
for i in *; do mv $i `echo $i | tr -d "'"`; done
```

After executing this command nothing is renamed.

Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: What error message do you see?  Do the names also contain spaces?

Comment: @Mikel There wasn't error message. Yes, the names contained spaces too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try something like this (`bash`):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *\'* ; do mv -v "$i" "${i/\'/}" ; done
```

This uses shell string replacement. You probably don't want to glob files that don't have `'` in them since the `mv` would fail. Without the `nullglob` option, the glob pattern itself would be passed to `mv` if there are no matching files.

Answer (score 6):

**Always put double quotes around variable substitutions `$foo` and command substitutions `$(foo)`** (unless you know why you need to leave them out and why it's ok to do so).

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | tr -d "'")"; done
```

This will mostly work, with a few restrictions:

- You'll get bad behavior or errors if a file name begins with `-`, because `mv` will interpret it as an option.
- This does not affect files whose name begins with `.`.
- With some setups, this will mangle backslashes in the `echo` command.
- Newlines at the end of the name are lost.

In ksh93, bash and zsh, you can write this with less hassle using the `${VARIABLE//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` construct. Adding `--` to `mv` takes care of file names beginning with `-`. If you have file names beginning with `.`, add `.*` or `.[^.]* ..?*` after `*` as needed.

```
for i in *; do mv -- "$i" "${i//\'/}"; done
```

In zsh, you can use [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv):

```
zmv '(*)' "\${1//\\'/}"
```

Under Debian, Ubuntu and other derivatives, you can use the [`rename`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=rename&sektion=1) Perl script.

```
rename "s/'//g" *
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume your problem is the file also had spaces in its name.  I can't reproduce your error without it.

```
$ touch "file" "user's file"
$ for i in *; do mv $i `echo $i | tr -d "'"`; done
mv: `file1' and `file1' are the same file
mv: target `file' is not a directory
```

So the reason it's failing is the second message: `target 'file' is not a directory`.

When your for loop sees a file with a space, it runs this:

```
mv user's file users file
```

So it thinks you're specifying three files (`user's`, `file`, and `users`), and a directory to move those files into (`file`).

Proper quoting of both should solve your immediate problem

```
$ for i in ./*; do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | tr -d "'")"; done
```

Comment: @xralf Note that there were still missing quotes in Mikel's last snippet, that would mangle multiple spaces and wildcards in file names.

Comment: I added `./*` in my edit.  This prevents file names like `-option` from being misinterpreted.