# Can't remove apostrophes from filenames in terminal

Tags: bash, zsh, filenames

I don't understand why zsh and bash (ls) show me lots of filename inside apostrophes, but not all:

```
'joe rilla - mauern fallen.mp3'
jokaz-alarmbereit.mp3
'yoshi blessed - everybody free.mp3'
```

I tried to remove the `'` like here with rename and bash:

[Removing apostrophe from all file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38017/removing-apostrophe-from-all-file-names)

But without success. It tells me "*A* and *B* are the same file".

How can I get rid of the apostrophes?

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't an apostrophe in the filename. The filenames that have whitespaces are getting 'wrapped'.

Comment: Ok. I see. I had the suspicion now but after the question was posted. thanks